# WebGL Fragment Shader for borders is warping

Tags: three.js, glsl, fragment-shader

**Background**

I'm working on a grand-strategy game where it is based on provinces. I use a bitmap to define those provinces just like a Paradox game.

[image]

I got the bitmap part to work correctly so I decided to make shader to define the borders of the provinces. The Shader is working by defining the borders, but it's positioned wrong and warps based on the position of the camera (I am using Three.js btw).

[image]
[image]

**Question**

How do I stop it from warping and make sure it's positioned correctly. The code for the Three.js material is below.

```js
this.Material = new ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: {
        resolution: { value: new Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ) },
        backbuffer: { value: this.Texture }
    },
    fragmentShader: `
        uniform vec2 resolution;
        uniform sampler2D backbuffer;

        varying vec2 vUv;

        vec4 getNeighborColor( float ox, float oy ) {
            float px = gl_FragCoord.x + ox;
            float py = gl_FragCoord.y + oy;

            vec2 p = vec2( px, py );
            vec2 position = ( p.xy / resolution.xy ) * vUv.xy;

            vec4 color = texture2D(backbuffer, position);

            return color;
        }
            
        void main( void ) {
            vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy ) * vUv.xy;
            vec4 color = texture2D(backbuffer, position);
                    
            vec4 nc = getNeighborColor( 0., -1. );
            vec4 ec = getNeighborColor( 1., 0. );
            vec4 sc = getNeighborColor( 0., 1. );
            vec4 wc = getNeighborColor( -1., 0. );

            if ( color != nc || color != ec || color != sc || color != wc ) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.,0.,0.,1.);
            } else {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.,1.,1.,1.);
            }
        }
    `,
    vertexShader: `
        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {
            vUv = uv;
        
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
    `
} )
```